# Huge bug in ie8 - closed tabs and browser windows don't actually close!

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I generally have about 5 - 10 IE windows open, and about 10 tabs in each of those.  I've noticed since installing IE8 that once I get too many tabs open, things start going wonky on the screen, similar to the windows desktop heap size issue:
http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2008/01/14/registry-setting-keeps-windows-from-wigging-out-when-you-open-lots-of-ie7-tabs.aspx

However, I have fixed that registry setting and all was well until I installed IE8.

Now, when I get lots of IE windows and tabs open, eventually things start to go weird (windows don't redraw correctly, etc).  So as a remedy, I try and close off as many tabs and windows as possible, which will clear things up for a while.  But once I get lots of stuff open later, I will see tabs that I closed literally hours ago show up in the browser window, but they are not clickable, and if you resize the browser, they disappear.  So it seems they aren't truly being unloaded.

Am I the only one seeing this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And they say reinstall -- [**Why does IE 8 hang so much?**](http://social.answers.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/InternetExplorer/thread/9121047e-48ba-40fc-8396-829bdea39b32)

If you can spare some time also read up [**Mozilla Preparing To Scrap Tabbed Browsing**](http://tech.slashdot.org/article.pl?sid=09/05/18/1227247)?
(warning, that is a Slashdot discussion reference, can go lots of places in a single page)

Comment: I've never had any problem with it hanging.  Other than this massive issue I'm having, I find it tolerable.